# jQuery's datepicker delete issue

Tags: jquery

I seem to be having a problem with the date picker.  Here is the current code I have:

jQuery:

```
$("txtDate").datepicker({
showOn:"both",
buttonImage:"calendar.png",
buttonImageOnly:true,
onClose: function() {
// do something here
}
});
```

HTML:

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtDate" Runat="server" />
```

This works fine until the user deletes a character from the textbox itself after selecting a date.  For example, if the user selects 01-01-2013, and then deletes the last digit, i.e. 3, all other date selections after that will have the last digit missing until a different year is selected.

How do I stop this from happening?  So basically, if the user deletes any characters from the selected date, selecting the same date again or any other date should not result in the last character missing.

Comment: You can make the textbox `readonly`, force the user to select the date from calendar only...

Comment: Can't remember was it was, but readonly gave me issues in the passed, something to do with certain other parts of my site not being able to read the data within the textbox when it's set to readonly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `$("txtDate").datepicker({...})` will target an element called "txtDate" (`<txtDate></txtDate`). jQuery selectors work just like CSS selectors, and in order to target an element by its `id` you'll need to prefix it with a `#`:

```js
$("#txtDate".datepicker({...});
```

Secondly, depending on how your workspace is set up, ASP.NET usually adds [somewhat random characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d04y8ss%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to the beginning of an ID to ensure that it remains unique throughout the page. This means that the actual markup will end up looking something along the lines of:

```html
<input id="ct100_ct109_txtDate" ... />
```

For this reason, you'll probably need to target something other than the element's ID *or* pass the ID into the JavaScript through ASP.NET.

--

I think [Asif's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220634/jquerys-datepicker-delete-issue#comment28445378_19220634) is probably the best solution to your problem: simply set your text box as [`readonly`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-readonly-attribute) to prevent its content being modified directly by the user. In ASP.NET, this is done using `ReadOnly`:

```html
<asp:TextBox id="txtDate" Runat="server" ReadOnly="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you could clear the textfield, if user deletes the data, like:

```
$("your_input_element").datepicker({
   showOn:"both",
   buttonImage:"calendar.png",
   buttonImageOnly:true,
   onClose: function() {
       // do something here
   }
}).keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
        $.datepicker._clearDate(this);
    }
});
```